# Font rendering of Helvetica-Neue different from Chrome to Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

The way the font Helvetica-Neue is getting rendered in chrome and firefox is different.

PFB the snapshot for the same.

[image]

Have also used the following styles:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You appear to be on an operating system that is not Mac OSX and that Moz property is OSX, i.e. Mac. Also bear in mind that both of these properties are non-standard and MDN recommends against using them. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth